# Does Debian 8 support secure boot?

Tags: operating-system, debian

So I've read Debian 'stretch' supports secure boot, but what about Debian 8('jessie')?
Besides, do you normally turn secureboot off when installing your OS?
Can you list the advantages and disadvantages of turning it off?

Comment: so when did you read that? *Debian 8*, codename 'jessie' has been released end of april 2015; before that it was "testing". so chances are high that the *testing* in your reading is actually *jessie* aka *Debian 8*. apart from that, this question is off-topic on [so] and should be migrated to [su]

Comment: You're right, i should probably post this question on Super User. But the testing version I'm talking about started as a copy of 'jessie' and its codename is 'stretch', so my question keeps unanswered :(

Comment: in any case you better update your question to change the ambiguous *testing* to the non-ambiguous *stretch*.